# Detect Boundries of the food

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmMij.jpg) to detect the food objects,
I used skimage to convert it into gray scale and make the threshold and [it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYxSM.jpg)

```
image=plt.imread('image.jpg')
gray = rgb2gray(image)
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
gray_r = gray.reshape(gray.shape[0]*gray.shape[1])
for i in range(gray_r.shape[0]):
  if gray_r[i] > gray_r.mean():
    gray_r[i] = 1
  else:
    gray_r[i] = 0
gray = gray_r.reshape(gray.shape[0],gray.shape[1])
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

I need to remove the black portion on the food to detect the boundary of the foods

How to do this.. Any help

Comment: You should include the code used to make this, and explain how it was insufficient

Comment: Hi, I uploaded the code, Could you please guide me how to detect the edge of the foods in image.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know `scikit-image` I was just trying to make it so others could help. If you were using `opencv`, you could use the [general tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) after using some [image processing](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc/py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html#py-table-of-content-imgproc) *namely Image Gradients or Canny edge detection* to find the areas you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you used is merely applying a binary threshold (mean value of the image) to convert a grayscale image to a binary one. Since food has various shape and contours, it would be difficult to segment them out. If you try edge detection, the boundary of the plates would be detected as well.

Comment: I used canny edge detection but it is not working. Would you suggest any algorithm..

Comment: You can possibly try cv2.findContours(), but I doubt it would work.